# Эмуляция нажатия кнопок в играх

Tags: python, разработка-игр, button, python-2.x

Когда пишу код для эмуляции нажатия кнопки "w" в игре, которая подразумевает движение, но по какой то причине персонаж не двигается и стоит до конца кода. Я пробовал несколько библиотек и даже перевел игру в окно и применил библиотеку pywinauto и прописал код к игре Portal:

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title="Portal - Direct3D 9")
main_window = app["Portal - Direct3D 9"]
```

все равно, при запуске кода максимум, что он может - это писать в консоль, но никак не влияет на персонажа.
Мне нужен элементарный код для движения персонажа вперед, допустим, на 2 секунды, после чего он остановится. Помогите, кто разбирается!
Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: последние строчки.  Я ведь написал что мне нужен элементарный код для движения персонажа вперед, допустим, на 2 секунды, после чего он остановится